# Obtaining boolean value from attribute for a particular Twitter user with Ruby and Twitter API

Tags: ruby, twitter, boolean

I'm trying to assign the boolean value from a Twitter user's attribute (i.e. 'verified') to a variable, but I"m not having much luck. I'm using Ruby -- here's the code:

```
profile = Twitter.users({"Oprah" => :verified})

    if profile == true
        puts "This profile is verfied."
    else
        puts "This profile is NOT verified."
    end
```

It always defaults to the else statement regardless of whether or not the Twitter user has been verified or not. I know I'm forgetting to do something simple. Any thoughts?

Comment: should it not be something like `profile = Twitter.users("Oprah").verified` or `profile = Twitter.users("Oprah")['verified']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
verified = Twitter.user("Oprah").verified

if verified
    puts "This profile is verfied."
else
    puts "This profile is NOT verified."
end
```

user `Twitter.user` for single user, and `Twitter.users` for many users

```
profiles = Twitter.users(["Oprah","dad"])
profiles.each do |profile|
  if profile.verified
     puts "#{profile.name} profile is verfied."
  else
     puts "#{profile.name} profile is NOT verified."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps profile is Array or Hash object. Better you try inspecting it first.

```
profile = Twitter.users({"Oprah" => :verified})
puts profile.inspect
```

Comment: When I inspect it, I see an empty hash in the server logs i.e. '[]'

Comment: Yes, comparing empty array with true always returns false. Also, the variable name should always reflect the object type. As you it returns a hash, you should use profiles, not profile, and try profiles.empty?